# Azure Free Space metric does not show any data

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I have a log analytics workspace and 2 VMs connected to it. The VMs do not have Guest-OS enabled.
When I navigate to the Log Analytics --> Log blade and run the Azure provided query for "% Free Space" nothing shows up at all.

Do I need to enable Guest-OS for the VMs ? I thought this metric was out-of-the-box by Azure. What am I missing here ?

More observations:
VM1 and VM2 are connected to the log workspace. I enabled guest-os for VM2 ONLY thinking that this is needed. When I ran this Free Space query with log analytics workspace as the scope, I could see the data for VM1 also which was strange.
So I concluded that Guest-OS is not needed for this metric.
So I removed Guest-OS and removed WADPerformaceCounterTable from the storage too.

And now I dont see ANY data for the query

Answer (score 0):

According to my test, if we want to monitor the servers available disk space using Azure Log Analytics, we need to have the Azure monitor agent installed on the VM’s you want to monitor and enable  Performance counters in Azure log analysis.. For further details about it, please refer to [the blog](https://pixelrobots.co.uk/2019/08/monitor-your-servers-available-disk-space-using-azure-log-analytics/).

For example(I use windows VM for test)

1. Enable the Log Analytics VM Extension. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/vm/quick-collect-azurevm?toc=/azure/azure-monitor/toc.json) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/log-analytics-agent#install-and-configure-agent)
2. Configuring Performance counters
   [image]
3. Query

```
erf
| where ObjectName == "LogicalDisk" or // the object name used in Windows records
ObjectName == "Logical Disk" // the object name used in Linux records
| where CounterName == "Free Megabytes"
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by InstanceName // arg_max over TimeGenerated returns the latest record
| project TimeGenerated, InstanceName, CounterValue, Computer, _ResourceId
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response Jim. All the steps you showed are in place for me. However I am further confused by the whole naming of it. 

Is my "Free Space" a log or a metric? If it is a log it makes sense that it works with a query. BUT then how can I also find it as a metric in Azure Monitor. (i am trtying to add attachments like you but I somehow cannot)

Comment: @user12589647 If you want to find it in Azure monitor, you need to enable Guest-OS for the VMs